# cakephp pull more than one record from same table for each result

Tags: cakephp-2.0, cakephp-model

Ok, this is a little complicated (to me anyways).  I would like to pull images from two records to put into a view for ONE result.

I have Unit, which belongs to Complex.  Each Unit and each Complex can have a record in the images table.

I would like to have my result for a particular Unit show all the images for Unit in the images table, plus a few images from its Complex (also stored in the images table).  Here are my models:

```
class Image extends AppModel {
    public $name='Image';
    var $belongsTo=array(
    'Unit'=>array (
        'className'=>'Unit',
        'foreignKey'=>'unit_id'
        ),
    'Complex'=>array (
        'className'=>'Complex',
        'foreignKey'=>'complex_id'
        ),
    'Restaurant'=>array (
        'className'=>'Restaurant',
        'foreignKey'=>'restaurant_id'
        )
    );


}

class Complex extends AppModel {
    public $name='Complex';
    public $hasMany=array('Unit');
    public $hasOne=array('Image');
    public $belongsTo=array(
        'Location'=>array(
            'className'=>'Location',
            'foreignKey'=>'location_id'
            )
    );






}

class Unit extends AppModel {
public $name='Unit';

public $belongsTo=array(
'User'=>array(
    'className'=>'User',
    'foreignKey'=>'user'
),
'Complex'=>array(
    'className'=>'Complex',
    'foreignKey'=>'complex_id'
),

'Location'=>array (
        'className'=>'Location',
        'foreignKey'=>'location_id'
        ),
);

public $hasOne=array('Image');

}
```

Here is my controller logic:

```
$this->paginate['Unit']=array(
        'limit'=>9,
        'order' => 'RAND()',
        'contain'=>array(
                'User'=>array('email'),
                'Complex'=>array('location_id'),
                'Location',
                'Image'
                ),
        'conditions'=>array(

                'Unit.active'=>1)   
    );
$data = $this->paginate('Unit');
$this->set('allaccommodations', $data);
```

You can see the results of a debug [here:](http://rentcondos4less.cloudmedia.biz/lodgings).  It pulls my image data for the Unit, but I need it to pull an Image array with both unit_id and complex_id.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In these cases you have to use different aliases for the Image model because the associative array can't hold two values with the same key.

```
class Complex extends AppModel {
    //...
    public $hasOne=array(
        'ComplexImage' => array(
            'className'=>'Image',
            'foreignKey'=>'complex_id'
        )
    );
}

class Unit extends AppModel {
    //...
    public $hasOne=array(
        'UnitImage' => array(
            'className'=>'Image',
            'foreignKey'=>'unit_id'
        )
    );
}
```

Then your query array would change to this:

```
$this->paginate['Unit'] = array(
    'limit' => 9,
    'order' => 'RAND()',
    'contain' => array(
        'User' => array('email'),
        'Complex' => array(
            'fields' => array('id', 'location_id'),
            'ComplexImage'
        ),
        'Location',
        'UnitImage'
    ),
    'conditions' => array(
        'Unit.active' => 1)
);
```

This also effects the way you access the models.

`$this->Unit->UnitImage->id;`

Comment: Hmm, I tried that, and debugging shows me that it pulls 'UnitImage', but not 'ComplexImage'.  Cake says: Warning (512): Model "Unit" is not associated with model "ComplexImage" [CORE/Cake/Model/Behavior/ContainableBehavior.php, line 339].  I copied and pasted your code, and made sure that there is both complex_id and unit_id in my image table.

Comment: **Update**  If I add both aliases to the Unit model, it no longer gives me a warning about ComplexImage not being associated, but it still returns a filled array for UnitImage and an empty array for ComplexImage.

Comment: Updated the paginate settings. The 'ComplexImage' wasn't directly associated with 'Unit', so it needed to be moved.

Comment: Well, I spoke too soon.  If you debug you see that it pulls the data for ComplexImage, but if you try to echo say $h['ComplexImage']['img1'] you get an undefined index error.  I tried actually putting into another foreach array like so:   <?php foreach($h['ComplexImage'] as $cimg) {
    echo $cimg['img1'];
    } ?>    but it gave me the same error plus an invalid argument to the foreach() function error.

Comment: Can you post a link to the debug?

Comment: Here is the link:  http://rentcondos4less.cloudmedia.biz/lodgings/debug  If you view source, I have added the controller code in the comments right above the footer.

Comment: I edited the paginate settings again, added id field to the Complex['fields']. Are you that `Complex` & `ComplexImage` both have the Containable behavior attached? `$this->Unit->Complex->ComplexImage->Behaviors->attach('Containable');`

Comment: *Sigh* didn't work.  I did that, no go.  I went into my debug.ctp file and added another foreach loop inside the original foreach foreach($h['ComplexImage'] as $img) {
 echo $img['img1'];
 }  And I got same 'undefined index' PLUS 'invalid argument supplied for foreach'

Comment: Is complex containable as well? `$this->Unit->Complex->Behaviors->attach('Containable');`

Comment: containable is attached to both Complex and ComplexImage, and still nothing.  Perhaps my view code is just screwy as I also have this problem in the Coupons model.

Comment: If it's not showing up in the results it's not the view that is the problem. My guess is it's in the associations. I think I'd have to see all of your code to figure it out, though.

Comment: It shows up in the debug results, but I cannot echo it out.  Maybe I'm trying to echo it the wrong way.  I will post the view code in my debug file again.

Comment: I thought I had something screwed up in my database causing the problem, but nope.  So still unresolved.  By the way, your help over these past few days has been incredible.  Thank you very much!

Comment: You're welcome. In your view code, replace `|` with `||`. `|` is a bitwise OR, which isn't what you want. Within the for loop you should be able to access `ComplexImage` with `$h['Complex']['ComplexImage']['img1']`. I recommend doing some PHP array exercises to better grasp how they work.

Comment: Holy monkey sheet, it finally worked.  You are my hero, truly.